# Error: The argument type 'Stream<PostsRecord>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Record'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, navigator

New to flutter here (and coding in general) but have an issue that I cannot figure out to solve. I am navigating to a page based off of a variable and need to pass in a Record. However, I cannot figure out how to pass a Record from the reference already on the page (postReference). I only want to read this document if the button is pressed also. Using Firebase/Firestore as the backend. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error

> Error: The argument type 'Stream' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PostsRecord'.

Code snippet below. I cannot figure out how to properly query the record to then pass to the Widget Builder.

```
class NotificationPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotificationPageWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotificationPageWidgetState createState() => _NotificationPageWidgetState();
}

class _NotificationPageWidgetState extends State<NotificationPageWidget> {
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: Text(
          'Notifications',
          style: FlutterFlowTheme.title1,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<List<UserNotificationsRecord>>(
                stream: queryUserNotificationsRecord(
                  queryBuilder: (userNotificationsRecord) =>
                      userNotificationsRecord
                          .where('notifiedUsers',
                              arrayContains: currentUserReference)
                          .orderBy('notificationTime', descending: true),
                ),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          color: FlutterFlowTheme.secondaryColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  List<UserNotificationsRecord>
                      listViewUserNotificationsRecordList = snapshot.data;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: listViewUserNotificationsRecordList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, listViewIndex) {
                      final listViewUserNotificationsRecord =
                          listViewUserNotificationsRecordList[listViewIndex];
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (listViewUserNotificationsRecord.initialPageName == '/commentsPage') {
                            final postRef = PostsRecord.getDocument(listViewUserNotificationsRecord.postReference);
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CommentsPageWidget(
                              activityRecord: postRef,
//This is where the error is occurring. Looking for a Record and not a Reference.
                            )
                            )
                            );
                          };
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this implemented: `PostsRecord.getDocument(listViewUserNotificationsRecord.postReference)`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included more of the snippet. I have added to the snippet to show how the listView is being built. Does this help answer your question?

Comment: Not really, as I'm having a hard time isolating where the problem occurs in this code, and then mapping that back to where the variables used in that line come from. Ideally it help if you can follow the guidance in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that is gets close to a state where we can copy/paste it to reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for patience and willingness to help! I am still learning even the syntax of flutter. I have edited the original question to hopefully give you the minimal example. The UsersNotificationsRecord contains a reference to the PostsRecord, but I cannot figure out how to get the PostsRecord from the reference held within the UsersNotificationsRecord and pass that to the CommentsPageWidget.

Comment: This leads me back to my first comment: How is `PostsRecord.getDocument(listViewUserNotificationsRecord.postReference)` implemented? As the [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I linked before suggests, you should start with a new project and reproduce the problem in as few steps as possible. Copy/pasting from your existing project leads to missing code, or too much code.